# TypeScript array modifications in called method not reflecting in calling function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following angular 6 calling-component-code:

```
this.appDowntimeService.getAllApplications(this.message, this.appDetails);
```

Here is the called service method:

```
  async getAllApplications(message: any[], appDetails: any[]) {
    this.http.get(environment.serverTMODowntime + '/tmodowntime.v1/downtime/apps/all', {headers: this.headers})
      .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
        message.length = 0;
        appDetails.length = 0;
        res.forEach(x => {
          message.push(x);
          x.details.forEach(y => {
            const appDetail = <ApplicationDetail>{};
            appDetail.createdDate = y.createdDate;
            appDetail.createdBy = y.createdBy;
            appDetail.updatedDate = y.updatedDate;
            appDetail.updatedBy = y.updatedBy;
            appDetails.push(appDetail);
          });
        });
        appDetails.sort((leftSide, rightSide) => {
          if (leftSide.startTime < rightSide.startTime) return -1;
          if (leftSide.startTime > rightSide.startTime) return 1;
          return 0;
        });
        this.updated.emit('success');
      });
  }
```

I expect changes to both arrays (message and appDetails) to be visible in calling-component-code.  However, only changes made  (inside service function call) to message array are showing up. Changes to appDetails array are not showing up in calling-component-code.

I am not able to tell why it works one way with one array and other way with the second array.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: and where you "check" for content of that array?

Comment: OR should I rather ask WHEN?

Comment: You do know this is **async** code right? Http calls are asyc.

Answer (score 0):

First: Check if your x.details has items.

Second: appDetail.startTime is never assigned a value to. So in the sort-function, null against null are compared. This is a bug. Assign a value to appDetail.startTime!

Comment: Thanks. I checked in debug mode. appDetails gets populated with few rows when we reach the end of the function logic.  I still have the problem. Also, changing appDetails to specific type did not help.

Comment: Yes. It populated rows in appDetails array when I stopped on emit row during debug session.

Comment: I edited the answer after your comments, it should work now.